# scaling up an SVM classifier

Tags: svm, accuracy

I am working on a problem of trying to classify materials using image data. I have tried several classifiers and have ended up that an SVM with a non-linear kernel gives me the best results up to now.

My problem is that when I create a training/testing set for e.g. 10 materials, everything works fine. When I am trying to create a training/testing set for e.g. 25 materials, classification accuracy drops dramatically.

Could you propose any solution to this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Apparently the new things look more or less like the old things. More generally, classification accuracy is an improper scoring rule that will tend to select the wrong model. Look into the field of proper scoring rules.

Answer (score 2):

From what I have understood, SVM, Linear regression and Naive Bayes classifier performs best on simple pattern complexity (e.g. <10 classes). So it's only natural that your accuracy starts dropping when you add more and more categories (here the materials).

If you want to achieve top level accuracy (>0.9) you might want to implement a neural networks and in your case, since you are treating image data, I suggest looking into CNN.

Comment: It is incorrect to simply say one model is better than another, due to the no free lunch theory. CNN might have produced promising empirical results in the field of computer vision, but it doesn't mean CNN is always better than SVM. Moreover, it is incorrect to simply relate pattern complexity with number of classes.